# rosbags - write uncompressed image to bag

Tags: python-3.x, ros, rviz

I'm new to ROS and running **ROS noetic** with the need to create a **ROS bag** containing **uncompressed greyscale** images.
Therefore, I use **rosbags-image==0.9.1** and according to their
[compressed example here](https://ternaris.gitlab.io/rosbags/examples/save_images.html)
I have prepared an example to save 2 *uncompressed* `mono8` images, stored on disk as *png*.
Image size is 225x224 which results in data size of 50400 bytes.

```py
# Test to store 225x224 mono8 images uncompressed in ros bag for noetic
import numpy
from rosbags.rosbag1 import Writer
from rosbags.serde import serialize_ros1, serialize_cdr
from rosbags.typesys.types import builtin_interfaces__msg__Time as Time
# from rosbags.typesys.types import sensor_msgs__msg__CompressedImage as CompressedImage
from rosbags.typesys.types import sensor_msgs__msg__Image as Image
from rosbags.typesys.types import std_msgs__msg__Header as Header
from cv2 import imread

TOPIC = '/camera'
FRAMEID = 'map'

# Contains filenames and their timestamps
IMAGES = [
    ('homer.png', 42),  # w x h = 225 x 224, 8bit
    ('marge.png', 43),  # w x h = 225 x 224, 8bit
]


def save_images() -> None:
    """Iterate over IMAGES and save to output bag."""
    with Writer('output.bag') as writer:
        conn = writer.add_connection(TOPIC, Image.__msgtype__)

        for path, timestamp in IMAGES:
            ii = imread(path, 0)  # test version 1: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
            dd = numpy.fromfile(path, dtype=numpy.uint8)  # version 2: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
            print(ii.size, dd.size)  
            # ii.size=50400 = correct uncompressed img data size 
            # vs dd.size=44157 = correct png filesize

            message = Image(
                Header(
                    stamp=Time(
                        sec=int(timestamp // 10**9),
                        nanosec=int(timestamp % 10**9),
                    ),
                    frame_id=FRAMEID,
                ),
                height=ii.shape[0], # 224
                width=ii.shape[1],  # 225
                encoding='mono8',  # 8bit
                is_bigendian=0,  # False
                step=ii.shape[1],  # 225
                # data=ii,  # ii.size = 50400=hxw, ERROR!!!
                # ValueError: memoryview assignment: lvalue and rvalue have different structures
                data=dd,  # dd.size = 44157=png-file size, # Runs, but bag fails to deserialize image in rviz
            )

            writer.write(
                conn,
                timestamp,
                serialize_ros1(message, Image.__msgtype__),
            )
save_images()
```

Can someone please explain, what's wrong with the code, why setting the (imho) correct ii data results in an error `ValueError: memoryview assignment: lvalue and rvalue have different structures`, while setting the smaller dd data can be written,
but seems to be wrong as well...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have very specific needs, I recommend you use cv_bridge to construct `sensor_msgs/Image` using its `cv2_to_imgmsg` method instead of doing this yourself.

Refer to:
http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython

Answer (score 0):

##### Regarding the issue with the `ii` (`imread`) data :

The `ValueError: memoryview assignment: ...` error comes from the image data being a 2D array, while the serialization expects a 1D array. Simply changing your `data=ii` (2D) for `data=ii.flatten()` (1D) fixes the issue.

##### Regarding the issue with the `dd` (`numpy.fromfile`) data:

Serialization of `ii` works because `numpy.fromfile()` reads data into a 1D array. As you found out, `ii.size` does not match `dd.size`, since `ii` contains the compressed image data. Using the `CompressedImage` ROS message with `format="png"` (as per the example) should work.